# Custom PhpSpec matcher and/or extension not working

Tags: php, phpspec

I'm trying to test if a class is final. Since I've not found a default matcher for this (or any other clean way of testing it), I decided to create a custom extension which adds a new matcher to do just that, but I can't get it to work.

I've tried it with an inline matcher, like so:

```
public function getMatchers(): array
{
    return [
        'beFinal' => function ($subject) {
            $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($subject);

            if (!$reflection->isFinal()) {
                throw new FailureException('Expected subject to be final, but it is not.');
            }
            return true;
        },
    ];
}
```

This works well enough when I call `$this->shouldBeFinal();`. The problem is that when I call `$this->shouldNotBeFinal();`, it outputs a generic message: `[obj:Class\To\Test] not expected to beFinal(), but it did.`, instead of one I'd like to show.

Another problem is that I don't want this for just one class. That's why I decided to make an extension for it.

Here's what I got:

**phpspec.yml**:

```
extensions:
    PhpSpecMatchers\Extension: ~
```

**PhpSpecMatchers/Extension.php**:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace PhpSpecMatchers;

use PhpSpec\ServiceContainer;
use PhpSpecMatchers\Matchers\BeFinalMatcher;

class Extension implements \PhpSpec\Extension
{
    public function load(ServiceContainer $container, array $params): void
    {
        $container->define(
            'php_spec_matchers.matchers.be_final',
            function ($c) {
                return new BeFinalMatcher();
            },
            ['matchers']
        );
    }
}
```

**PhpSpecMatchers/Matchers/BeFinalMatcher.php**:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace PhpSpecMatchers\Matchers;

use PhpSpec\Exception\Example\FailureException;
use PhpSpec\Matcher\BasicMatcher;

class BeFinalMatcher extends BasicMatcher
{
    public function supports(string $name, $subject, array $arguments): bool
    {
        return $name === 'beFinal';
    }

    public function getPriority(): int
    {
        return 0;
    }

    protected function matches($subject, array $arguments): bool
    {
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($subject);

        return $reflection->isFinal();
    }

    protected function getFailureException(string $name, $subject, array $arguments): FailureException
    {
        return new FailureException('Expected subject to not be final, but it is.');
    }

    protected function getNegativeFailureException(string $name, $subject, array $arguments): FailureException
    {
        return new FailureException('Expected subject to be final, but it is not.');
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to call `$this->beFinal();` with this configuration, the spec is broken and shows the following message: `method [array:2] not found.`. If I add an **isFinal()** method to the class I'm testing and return true for example, it passes for `$this->shouldBeFinal();` and fails for `$this->shouldNotBeFinal();`, but I don't want to add that method. I should just work without it and for as far as I understand it should be able to work like that, right?

I've also tried adding custom **suites** to my **phpspec.yml**, like so:

```
suites:
    matchers:
        namespace: PhpSpecMatchers\Matchers
        psr4_prefix: PhpSpecMatchers\Matchers
        src_path: src/PhpSpecMatchers/Matchers
        spec_prefix: spec/PhpSpecMathcers/Matchers
```

But that doesn't change anything. I've also tried to add the following config to **phpspec.yml**:

```
extensions:
    PhpSpecMatchers\Extension:
        php_spec_matchers:
        src_path: src
        spec_path: spec
```

That also doesn't change anything.

One other thing I've tried was to ditch the extension approach and just declare my mather in **phpspec.yml**, like so:

```
matchers:
    - PhpSpecMatchers\Matchers\BeFinalMatcher
```

As you might expect: same results.

The loading in **PhpSpecMatchers\Extension** does get called (tested by a simple `var_dump(…);`), but it doesn't seem to reach anything within **PhpSpecMatchers\Matchers\BeFinalMatcher**, since I don't get any output from any `var_dump(…);`

I've followed tutorials and examples from symfonycasts, phpspec docs itself and some other github project I found, they're all almost identically to my code (except namespaces, directory structures and stuff like that), so I'm kind of at a loss here.

How do I get it to a point where I can successfully call `$this->shouldBeFinal();` and `$this->shouldNotBeFinal();`?

Many thanks to whovere can help me out here.

P.S.: I've also posted this [issue](https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec/issues/1246) on phpspec's github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the priority was too low (see [this comment](https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec/issues/1246#issuecomment-475521006) my phpspec's github issue). **PhpSpec\Matcher\IdentityMatcher** (where the `shouldBe` comes from) extends from **PhpSpec\Matcher\BasicMatcher** where the priority is set to 100. 
Since mine was set to 0 it got to mine first (I think) and therefore didn't execute properly. I've set my priority to 101 and it works flawlessly (except I had switched the positive and negative messages, I found out).

Comment: You should publish your extension on Packagist !

Comment: @DamianDziaduch good idea. I'll try to get it set-up (no prior experience with creating packages) and post a link here once it's done.

Comment: @DamianDziaduch, as promised I've published an initial working version on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/nico-vromans/phpspec-matchers#0.1.0) (I'll update the readme and version number sometime soon).